# Prove rearrangement of harmonic series tends to 1 or -1

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove that a rearrangement of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}$ has a subsequence that tends to 1 or -1 or prove otherwise.

I did a proof that brought me to a converging limit to $\frac{\log{2}}{2}$. But I'm struggling to find an obvious rearrangement that would tend to either of these limits.

Comment: Okay, there is a revision to the question.. I misinterpreted how my teacher was asking the question. I found out the methodology for rearranging the sequence so it tends to a specific number.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as a series that doesn't converge absolutely, you can rearrange it to converge to anything you want.  To do this, you just pick either positive or negative terms, whichever will get you closer to your goal.  Since the terms tend to zero, this rearranged sequence will get you wherever you want.

Comment: Right, I understand that you can manipulate the order of a series to yield a converging value. I'm just not entirely sure how to select a rearrangement such that it tends to a specific number, like 1 or -1.